# From 18.04 to 20.04 in a PC with 2 HDs won't work

Tags: upgrade, hard-drive, 20.04

Since 16.04, my laptop HDs are configured as:

HD 1 has 3 partitions: first is "/", second is /Home, and the third is mounted as /media.

HD 2 is not partitioned and is also mounted as /media.

Both HDs contains data. How may I mount them in 20.04?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you could mount *two* partitions on the same mount point, then you were taking advantage of a terrible bug, and good thing it's fixed now. How could you choose which partition a write would occur upon?

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many mount points as you wish, and place those mount points anywhere you wish. You
can also use existing directories as mount points.

- One partition (mount) per mountpoint.

Examples:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/aaa
$ pmount /dev/sda3 aaa

$ sudo mkdir /var/mountpoint1
$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sdm2 /var/mountpoint1
$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sdm6 /media
$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sdm3 /mnt
```